# How to pass ADDITIONAL arguments to an existing callback function

Tags: javascript, closures

I'm unable to find answers to this, although it should be a relatively common issue.  All other questions seem to relate to simply adding variables to an empty closure.

I have a callback which takes two arguments; `err` and `docs`, which I still need, but also want to add an additional argument of `data.

```
db.findOne().exec(function (err, docs) {
    // err is defined
    // docs is defined
});
```

I need to pass `data` along with it, so assumed I could do this:

```
db.findOne().exec(function (err, docs, data) {
    // err is defined
    // docs is defined
}(data));
```

This doesn't work.  So, I tried the following:

```
db.findOne().exec(function (err, docs, data) {
    // err is null
    // docs is null
}(null, null, data));
```

This killed the original variables `err` and `docs` as well.

So, how would I go about doing this?

Comment: `function (err, docs, data) {` should return `inner function` as a handler of `.exec`

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use the `data` variable inside the callback as long as this variable is defined in the outer scope (just before calling the `db.findOne()` method):

```
var data = ...
db.findOne().exec(function (err, docs) {
    // err is defined
    // docs is defined
    // data is defined
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap your function within callback function .

if you have function like :

```
db.findOne().exec(function (err, docs) {
    // err is defined
    // docs is defined
});
```

you can use following function to pass additional parameters:

```
db.findOne().exec(function (err, docs) {
var data={a:'a'};
    yourFunction(err, docs, data);
});

function yourFunction(err, docs, data){
// access data here
}
```